# Drools unable to import projects from (Git Lab) to Workbench

Tags: drools, redhat-brms

I am using Red Hat BRMS 6 to clone my remote repository project into workbench (Business central). It says cloning is successful but unable to open the project in editor.

**Logs: 2018-04-02 18:47:05,793 INFO  [org.kie.workbench.common.services.backend.service.KieService] (default task-14) File: pom.xml, full path [default://master@drools-bc-sync-sample/pom.xml] was not within a Project. Project Name cannot be set.**

**Remote Repository:** https://github.com/sureshpec04/drools-bc-sync-sample

Any idea on how to resolve this error?

**Update:**
I am able to clone the repository now and create a project in Business central. However post-commit hook is not working. Meaning, my repository does not get updated with new files created in Business central.

post commit file:
/tools/appsw/jboss/brms/data/.niogit/drools-bc-sample.git/hooks
Contents:

## !/bin/sh

git push origin master

permission is set to 777.

Comment: Your project, while valid as a maven perspective, does not follow the Business Central folder structure. I would advice you to remove all the content of your distant repository, clone it as empty repository, then use Business Central to create the proper structure (by creating new project, setting maven dependencies and uploading DRL files). Please note that a commit hook is necessary on the server in the git clone to trigger the remote push when committing in Business Central (aka "save" button).

Comment: Thanks Wis. I will try this and update you. Just curious to know is this the process to be followed or a workaround for Business central to connect with remote repository?

Comment: I tried by having an empty repository in GitLab and now I get no such element exception. Updated the question with error logs. Am I still miss anything here?

Comment: Ho, I remember this error. Business Central cannot clone an empty repository. You should add a single file (for instance a README file at the root of your repository) to avoid this clone problem. And this is the standard way with business central. For more material on commit hook, have a look at [this link](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_jboss_bpm_suite/6.4/html/administration_and_configuration_guide/chap_repository_hooks#configuring_git_hooks), specifically the point #7 which start with _Create a file named post-commit with the permissions..._

Comment: I added the README file and cloned repository. It says repository cloned successfully but not able to create any DRL file inside the project. I can see FileSystemNotFoundException in the logs. Updated my question with the logs.

Comment: I realized that I need to create a new project and only the repository is cloned. Now I am able to create DRL files however post commit is not working. Have updated the post-commit file contents in the question. Please let me know if anything else is missed out.

Comment: Do you have git installed on your server ? The automatic git push with hooks is possible in GIT, not something specific to Business Central. Also, you might need to register credentials into GIT and/or to configure an SSL certificate chain. Alternately, you can set the SSL verification into GIT to false (both config can be done with --global so you dont have to do it again for each cloned repository). Have a look at GIT manual for these.